# Putting two async subscriptions in one Angular *ngIf statement

Tags: angular, observable, angular-observable

I have the following in my component template:

`<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user>...</div>`

Within the above `div` I would like to use the async pipe to subscribe to another observable only once, and use it just like `user` above throughout the template. So for instance, would something like this be possible:

```html
<ng-template *ngIf="language$ | async as language>
<div *ngIf=" user$ | async as user>
  <p>All template code that would use both {{user}} and {{language}} would go in between</p>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Or can this even be combined in one statement?

Comment: I think you're asking if you can introduce "user" as a new template variable, and the answer is no. The async pipe just yields the value as part of the expression. You would have to use the async pipe everywhere in the template you want to use the user value.

Comment: All the logic I need is within the `div` above. I therefore do not need to reintroduce `user` as a variable anywhere else, since I already have it.

Comment: Please add more code that will explain what you are trying to do

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/xiOeJ5pbz2jmx8TIx4c0?p=preview

Comment: Right, my only issue here is that I'm using an `*ngIf` for a value that I know for a fact exists, which is in this case the language observable.

Comment: Please reproduce it in plunker

Comment: I don't know how, hence my question lol -- is it possible to yield the `language$` observable with the `async` pipe without using `*ngIf`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular2/43172992#43172992 Anyway you have to use structural directive for that

Comment: *That's* what I was looking for, thank you! Am I blind or does this exist nowhere in the docs?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use object as variable:

```html
<div *ngIf="{ language: language$ | async, user: user$ | async } as userLanguage">
    <b>{{userLanguage.language}}</b> and <b>{{userLanguage.user}}</b>
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9xKg4CidTqkzyZrHAWS7?p=preview)**

See also

- [How to declare a variable in a template in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular2/43172992#43172992)

Comment: One more question please: any performance hinderance to this method vs. adding an extra `ng-container` wrapper as you've suggested in your plunkr?

Comment: There is no much difference between `<ng-container *ngIf><div></div></ng-container>` and `<div *ngIf></div>`  but `ng-container` will generate more code that angular should handle

Comment: @Sammy We usually use `ng-container` if we have more than one structural directive on element

Comment: @Sammy You can compare it here https://plnkr.co/edit/7Yd0IWEmMdQolKHf6bhw?p=preview

Comment: Although this does subscribe to both observables at once, the solution is misleading as the resulting object is always truthy regardless of the state of the observables e.g. `{ language: undefined, user: undefined }`. Using `{{ userLanguage.user.id }}` would result in an error.

Comment: @Frayt raises a pretty valid point here - it kinda goes against the whole point of the *ngIf in the first place

Answer (score 13):

The problem with using "object as variable" is that it doesn't have the same behavior as the code in the question (plus it's a mild abuse of *ngIf to have it always evaluate to true). To get the desired behavior you need:

```
<div *ngIf="{ language: language$ | async, user: user$ | async } as userLanguage">
   <ng-container *ngIf="userLanguage.language && userLanguage.user"> 
      <b>{{userLanguage.language}}</b> and <b>{{userLanguage.user}}</b>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

While the other solutions work, they slightly abuse the purpose of `ngIf` which should only optionally render a template. I've written an `ngxInit` directive that always renders even if the expression result is "falsy".

```html
<div *ngxInit="{ language: language$ | async, user: user$ | async } as userLanguage">
   <!-- content -->
</div>
```

see https://github.com/amitport/ngx-init