# Angular 4: How to disable button with two condition and asynchronous flag?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-forms, multiple-conditions

**Scenario**

I am trying to disable [disabled] a button and select a class [ngClass] through two conditions:

1st: Input text is required.

2nd: Asynchronous flag is requiredTrue. I have a dependency about demand a challenge against a remote server which is the trigger to enable this button.

Well, I am using a formGroup validation like this:

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
     this.form = this.fb.group({
        'inputSMS': [null, Validators.required],
        'button': [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
     })
  }
```

1st condition = inputSMS; 2nd = button.

In my HTML I use this code for 1st condition:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
  <div [formGroup]="form">
    <label class="col-xs-4 F sms-codigo-sms">SMS Code</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input class="form-control sms-rect7" [(ngModel)]="inputSMS" formControlName="inputSMS" name="inputSMS" maxlength="20" type="numbers">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this for 2nd:

```
<div class="form-group row text-center">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="btn-group">
         <button [ngClass]="!form.valid ? 'sms-btn-disabled' : 'sms-btn'" 
         type="button" style="float: left;" [disabled]="!form.valid"  
         formControlName="button" (click)="check()">Validate</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**Problem**

I recieved correctly the asynchronous flag with a subject. I checked it. And 1st condition is true. But I do not know why is not enables button when conditions are true. It is as if is not detecting event changes. I only used ngModel with inputs but I am not sure if i could use it here. Do you know how can I resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the complete HTML form code?

Comment: I edited the post @KarthickManoharan , thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Finally, I solved this problem not using FormGroup. Due to I have an observable to notify if the challenge arrived I used two different controls. One of them is known control "form.valid" and the another one is an attribute of the class which it is updates when reponse of the observable arrives. Then I set this two properties as conditions. Here code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button [ngClass]="(!form.valid || !buttonValidate) ? 'sms-font sms-btn-disabled' : 'sms-font sms-btn'" type="button""
    [disabled]="(!form.valid || !buttonValidate)" (click)="check()">Validate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it Not in the template?
Yes with `combineLatest`. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46103424/848755

Answer (score 3):

> you try with ngOnChanges like this

in typescript

```
ngOnChanges() {
 this.signIn = false;
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      uname: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      password: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
  }
```

in html

```
 <button [class]="put your condition here" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Login</button>
```

no need of this one

```
 'button': [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
```

Comment: First of all, thank you by your time. But this solution not works for this scenario because I need to have an asynchronous flag to ensure that the buttton can be enabled. The problem here is about how can I use this flag, tested ok, to validate the form control of 1st condition and 2nd. I do not know how to "binding" the variable button to the formGroup Validator.

Comment: Why you want to add button to validator explain me clearly

Comment: Finally I solved the problem Soumya. Posted below. Thank you.