# Extract pipeable operator as function in RXJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    take(1),
    map(val => // doSomething),
    exhaustMap(val => 
      // someInner observable logic
      return of({someValue})
    )
).subscribe(finalVal => doSomething());
```

Now this code in the `exhaustMap` is repeated in several components and I'd like to extract it as an external function.

I have tried the following

```
  myExhaust(obs: Observable<any>): Observable<{ someValue: SomeClass }> {
    return obs.pipe(
      exhaustMap((val) => { 
           // do some stuff
           return of({someValue})
      })
    );
  }
```

But then I dont know how to plug it in the original code (that if the function code itself is correct)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically creating a custom operator. You are on the right track. You have to make a function that takes an observable and returns a new one.

```
function myExhaust<T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
    return input$ => input$.pipe(
       exhaustMap((val) => { 
           // do some stuff
           return of({someValue})
       }))
}
```

Now you can use myExhaust instead of exaustMap in your pipe.

Comment: What about passing parameters to the custom operator?

Answer (score 1):

Your `utility` seems fine and here's how you can pass the utility to the pipe:

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
take(1),
 myExhaust,
).subscribe(finalVal => doSomething());
```

[Here's the working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-91bwey)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regular shared `function` with this logic and use it in any components:

```js
// set appropriate generic types for your case
// it's just an example 
export function fun<T>(data: T): Observable<T> {
  // do your stuff
  return of<T>(data);
}

// usage
this.form.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    map(val => // doSomething),
    exhaustMap(val => fun(val))
  )
  .subscribe(finalVal => doSomething());
```

But if you need to combine this logic **only** with `exhaustMap` operator you need custom pipeable operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pipe` function to combine existing operators:

```
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

function discardOddDoubleEven() {
  return pipe(
    filter((v) => !(v % 2)),
    map((v) => v + v)
  );
}
```

Please refer the official documentation for the details: https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators#use-the-pipe-function-to-make-new-operators