# Extract pipeable operator as generic function in RXJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

How to extract the following pipe operator to a generic function

```
.pipe(map((products: IProduct[]) => products.map((product: IProduct) => product.title)));
```

Compare to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69377067/7096274) answer I tried a generic variant:

```
static mapPropertiesToArray<T extends object>( property: string ){
    return pipe(map((objects: T[]) => objects.map((item: T) => item[property as keyof T])));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than casting `property`, define it as a key of T.  Also, `pipe()` is unnecessary since you're not combining operators:

```js
function mapPropertiesToArray<T>(property: keyof T) {
  return map((objects: T[]) => objects.map((item: T) => item[property]));
}
```

This ensures a use like `of(myArray).pipe(mapPropertiesToArray('title'))` throws an error if `title` isn't a valid attribute

Edit: your comment made me realize this would return a union type if T's keys' values have differing types.  We need slightly more precise typing:

```js
function mapPropertiesToArray<T, P extends keyof T>(property: P) {
  return map((objects: T[]) => objects.map(item => item[property]));
}
```

Comment: Can I skip the outer map function?

Comment: What is the return type of your function?

Comment: You can absolutely skip the outer map function, and include it in your `.pipe()` instead.  That keeps the typing of the pure function simple (returning T[keyof T][]).  With the map left inside, it returns an OperatorFunction (returning T[keyof T][]).

Comment: can u please show me `mapPropertiesToArray<T>(property: keyof T)` when adding both modifications?

Comment: function mapPropertiesToArray<T, P extends keyof T>(property: P): (objects: T[])=>T[P][] {
  return objects => objects.map(item => item[property])
}