# set value of typescript variable from html template in angular

Tags: angular

How to set expression value to typescript local variable in HTML template 
I am trying to assign expression value to the variable like this:

```html
<span *ngIf="IsRangeValidate = !(section.FOFormFieldList[fieldIndex].FOFormFieldResponseText>=fieldInfo.MinVal && section.FOFormFieldList[fieldIndex].FOFormFieldResponseText<=fieldInfo.MaxVal)" class="text-danger">Value should be between {{fieldInfo.MinVal}} - {{fieldInfo.MaxVal}}</span>
```

The expression will return true/false value.
IsRangeValidate is TypeScript boolean variable and I want to assign expression result to this variable from HTML template

Comment: May be this answer can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store actually value in `IsRangeValidate`. You can create a getter in your component and use it.

```
 get isRangeValidate() {
   const text = this.section.FOFormFieldList[fieldIndex].FOFormFieldResponseText;
   return text >= this.fieldInfo.MinVal && text <= this.fieldInfo.MaxVal)
 }
```

And use this getter in your template:

```
 <span *ngIf="isRangeValidate" class="text-danger">Value should be between {{fieldInfo.MinVal}} - {{fieldInfo.MaxVal}}</span>
```

I hope this answer is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, @Natalya I know this but actually, I don't want to write code in typescript I just want to do same from HTML template.