# How to create an angular template variable

Tags: angular

I have several buttons that are disabled based on what a function returns. How can I reuse the value returned from `isDisabled(product)` without calling `isDisabled(product)` for every single button? The calculations within isDisabled() is long so I don't want to have to repeat it.

Currently the code looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of prodList">
   <button [disabled]=isDisabled(product)>...</button>
   <button [disabled]=isDisabled(product)>...</button>
   <button [disabled]=isDisabled(product)>...</button>
   <button [disabled]=isDisabled(product)>...</button>
   <button [disabled]=isDisabled(product)>...</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your controls in `ng-container` with `ngIf` like:

```html
<div *ngFor="let product of prodList">
  <ng-container *ngIf="{ disabled: isDisabled(product) } as result">
   <button [disabled]="result.disabled">...</button>
   <button [disabled]="result.disabled">...</button>
   <button [disabled]="result.disabled">...</button>
   ...
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

See also

- [How to declare a variable in a template in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular2/43172992#43172992)