# Ng Templates and Calling a Function/Method on the Bound Component

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Here is some simple template markup:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="let ud = getUpdated()">
  <label>Updated</label>
  <span>{{ud | date:'MMM/y'}}</span>
</ng-container>
```

Now, while the method getUpdated() is defined on the bound component, two issues arise. Typescript complains:

> [Angular] TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

and further issues are expressed in subsequent blocks.
Then, in lieu of building a full-blown @Pipe for this one-off `getUpdated()`, what am I missing to make this work?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: I did but read in a confusing way. I have clarified in update.

Answer (score 2):

This highlights differences in syntax between use of [NgForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) and NgIf.

From the docs:

```
// NgForOf provides several exported values that
// can be aliased to local variables:

<li *ngFor="let user of userObservable | async as users; index as i; first as isFirst">
   {{i}}/{{users.length}}. {{user}} <span *ngIf="isFirst">default</span>
</li>
```

Two options are available to assign to a template-local variable in-place:

1) Using `as` syntax:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="getUpdated() as ud">
  <label>Updated</label>
  <span>{{ ud | date: 'MMM/y' }}</span>
</ng-container>
```

2) Using `let` syntax:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="getUpdated(); let ud">
  <label>Updated</label>
  <span>{{ ud | date: 'MMM/y' }}</span>
</ng-container>
```

See also

- [How to declare a variable in a template in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular2/43172992#43172992)