# Way to declare a variable from within a template?

Tags: angular

I find myself writing code like this:

```
<div *ngIf="globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff != null">
    <span [ngStyle]="globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.street1Style" *ngIf="globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.street1.length > 0">{{globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.street1}}<br /></span>
    <span *ngIf="globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.street2.length > 0">{{globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.street2}}<br /></span>
    <span *ngIf="globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.city.length > 0">{{globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.city}},</span>
    <span *ngIf="globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.state.length > 0">{{globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.state}},</span>
    <span *ngIf="globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.zip.length > 0">,{{globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonParent][item.jsonName].locationADiff.zip}}</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to simplify that? I'd like to set a single variable, such as "myVar" equal to "globals.fieldErrors[item.jsonparent][item.jsonName]" to reduce verbosity.

Comment: what about [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14985) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use it like :**

```
<div *ngIf="{ a: 1, b: 2 }; let variable">
  <span>{{variable.a}}</span>
  <span>{{variable.b}}</span>
</div>
```

For more detail read : [How to declare a variable in a template in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular2)

Answer to your comment is :

> Cool, thanks. It works, but means I need a separate  with its own
>   *ngIf to test if locationADiff != null. Then another inner  that creates the variable. Any idea if there is a way to combine both the
>   test and variable creation into a single *ngIf?

```
<div *ngIf="checkCondition && { a: 1, b: 2 }; let variable">
  <span>{{variable.a}}</span>
  <span>{{variable.b}}</span>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-let-template)**

Comment: Cool, thanks. It works, but means I need a separate <div> with its own *ngIf to test if locationADiff != null. Then another inner <div> that creates the variable.

Any idea if there is a way to combine both the test and variable creation into a single *ngIf?