# How to assign result of async pipe to variable without *ngIf in Angular 6

Tags: angular

Is it possible to assign (areShipsExpanded$ | async) to variable without *ngIf? Because in case that this is flag `true`/`false` when I have: `*ngIf="(areShipsExpanded$ | async) as flag"` then button is not displaying in case of false.

And I would like something like this:

```
<button *let="(areShipsExpanded$ | async) as flag"
   (click)="expandAllShips(flag)">{{(flag ? "Collapse" : "Expand"}}
</button>
```

Comment: Why don't you do `<button  (click)="expandAllShips(flag)">{{(areShipsExpanded$ | async ? "Collapse" : "Expand"}}
</button>`

Comment: `(click)="expandAllShips(flag)` because of that?

Comment: Why not subscribe to `areShipsExpanded$` in component and assign it to a `flag` property?

Comment: Sure I can, but I was wondering whether is possible to do it directly from async :)

Comment: Here's another way from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40751358/2604813 -- <div *ngFor="let flag of [areShipsExpanded$ | async]"></div>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a variable in a template in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular)

Answer (score 58):

Little late to the party here but I found a great example of how to do this from this [medium article](https://medium.com/@yurykatkov/how-to-avoid-multiple-async-pipes-in-angular-ff0d51a8d368)

You still use `*ngIf` but you make sure that it always evaluates truthy by passing in a new object with your observable value as a property.

```
<div *ngIf="{value1: myObs$ | async} as valuesObj">
    {{ valuesObject.value1 }}
</div>
```

IMO this is still a little hacky but much less hacky than the other answer or creating your own `*ngLet` directive.

As mentioned in the article, this is also a good way to group together multiple observable values in multiple object properties so you don't have to have multiple `async` statements or nested `<ng-container>` elements.

Comment: There's a number of `*ngLet` implementations out there, but this saved adding another dependency 

Comment: A little hacky? That's an ugly workaround that abuses the language. I strongly discourage this. Yet again, JavaScript is hacky by definition, that's why we moved to TypeScript a long time ago.

Answer (score 16):

You can do it using `ng-template` and `ng-container`

```
<ng-template #myTempl let-flag="areShipsExpand">
      <button
   (click)="expandAllShips(flag)">{{flag ? "Collapse" : "Expand"}}
  </button>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTempl; context:{areShipsExpand: areShipsExpanded$ | async}"></ng-container>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yz4a1h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 10):

Use the `*ngrxLet` directive from [@ngrx/component](https://ngrx.io/guide/component/let)

```
<ng-container *ngrxLet="observableNumber$ as n">
   <app-number [number]="n">
   </app-number>
</ng-container>
```

Visibility of the element containing the `ngrxLet` directive is not affected by the value of the observable expression.

Comment: This is still in the experimental phase. 2022. Angular 14.

Answer (score 0):

I've even used this for binding's value

```
(someObs$ | async).propName
```