# Is there a way to use an observable object's properties in template controls with async than repeating "(obs$ | async)" everywhere?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have an observable that fetches information from the backend which I then use to fill values in a form like this:

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="row">
      <mat-select
        name="selectField"
        [options]="someOptions"
        [value]="(store.observable$ | async).selectFieldValue"
        [required]="true"
      >
      </mat-select>
      <mat-input
        name="inputField"
        [required]="true"
        [value]="(store.observable$ | async).inputfieldValue"
      >
      </mat-input>
      <mat-input
        name="otherInputField"
        [required]="true"
        [value]="(store.observable$ | async).otherInputFieldValue"
      >
      </mat-input>
      ...
  </div>
</div>
```

The observable comes from a selector in my component's ComponentStore:

```
export class MyComponentStore extends ComponentStore<MyStoreClass> {
  constructor(
    private service: MyHttpService,
  ) {
    super({ ... });
  }

  readonly observable$ = this.select((state) => state.storeClass);

  readonly updateObservable = this.updater(
    (state, payload: SomeClass) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        observable: payload
      };
    }
  );

  getObservableInfo = this.effect((req$: Observable<void>) => {
    return req$.pipe(
      switchMap((_) => this.service.getInfo()),
      map((payload) => this.updateObservable(payload.data))
    );
  })
}
```

I then call `this.store.getObservableInfo()` in my component's `ngOnInit`. I was getting an *ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError* error if I tried to do this:

```
<div class="column" *ngIf="(store.observable$ | async); let observable">
  <div class="row">
      <mat-select
        name="selectField"
        [options]="someOptions"
        [value]="observable.selectFieldValue"
        [required]="true"
      >
      ...
```

So I dismissed that idea. But I'm bothered by having to write `(store.observable$ | async)` in each of my controls' values. Is there a way to declare that as a variable somewhere and simplify it like you can do with *ngIf *without* using *ngIf (to avoid the error)?

Thank you

Comment: My first thought would be that if `ngIf` is causing that error, that there may be something more wrong somewhere else. If you are using NgRx, then your data should be immutable, which should mean that you should not get an "expression changed" error. Is there any way to build a *simple* stackblitz that demonstrates the issue? (With NgRx I'd almost assume the answer to that may be no. LOL)

Comment: @DeborahK give me some time and I'll see if I can set something up.

Comment: I'm looking at this: `      return {
        ...state,
        observable: payload
      };` If payload is an object, I assume this should be making a copy of it, not assigning a reference?

Comment: (And you might want to remove "simpler" from your post title. I think that may be why your question is getting voted down and marked to close. This may be construed to mean you want an opinion and opinion questions are a "no-no" here.) :-(

Comment: @DeborahK I'll make those editions. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this to make a copy of the payload instead of a direct reference:

```
  readonly updateObservable = this.updater(
    (state, payload: SomeClass) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        observable: {...payload}
      };
    }
  );
```

That may resolve your `expressionChangedAfterCheck` error. If not, there is more info on that error and correction ideas here: https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

If you can resolve that error, then you can use an `ngIf` like in the first (now deleted) answer:

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="row" *ngIf="store.observable$ | async as storeObservable">
      <mat-select
        name="selectField"
        [options]="someOptions"
        [value]="storeObservable.selectFieldValue"
        [required]="true"
      >
      </mat-select>
      <mat-input
        name="inputField"
        [required]="true"
        [value]="storeObservable.inputfieldValue"
      >
      </mat-input>
      <mat-input
        name="otherInputField"
        [required]="true"
        [value]="storeObservable.otherInputFieldValue"
      >
      </mat-input>
      ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556292/how-to-assign-result-of-async-pipe-to-variable-without-ngif-in-angular-6), you can probably go with a combination of `ng-template` and `ng-container`, something like this:

```
<ng-container
  *ngTemplateOutlet="myControls; context: { data: observable$ | async }"
></ng-container>

<ng-template #myControls let-data="data">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <mat-select
        name="selectField"
        [options]="someOptions"
        [value]="data.selectFieldValue"
        [required]="true"
      >
      </mat-select>
      <mat-input
        name="inputField"
        [required]="true"
        [value]="data.inputfieldValue"
      >
      </mat-input>
      <mat-input
        name="otherInputField"
        [required]="true"
        [value]="data.otherInputFieldValue"
      >
      </mat-input>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```