# Prevent click event from firing after a custom event

Tags: javascript, angular, mouseevent, dom-events

There is no "`mousehold`" event, so I wrote one:

```
import {
  Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[custMousehold]' })
export class MouseholdDirective {

  @Input() duration: number = 350; // ms
  @Output() mousehold: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  public timeout: NodeJS.Timer;

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  mousedown(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (event.which !== 1) return; // left mouse button only
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.mousehold.emit(event);
    }, this.duration);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseup')
  mouseup() { clearTimeout(this.timeout); }

}
```

This is how I attach it to an element:

```
<span custMousehold (mousehold)="do something ...
```

It works great. But I also have a `click` event on this same element:

```
<span custMousehold (mousehold)="do something" (click)="do something else ...
```

And I want the `click` event to only fire if `mousehold` did not fire.
I've been trying with `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` all over the code but they don't make a difference. The `click` always fires.

Comment: why not emit {...event,hold:true} or {...event,hold:false} according the timeout and only use a unique function?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter a `click` event to check if `mousehold` was emitted. If so, just ignore `click` event.

I'm providing working [plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/TS0RaBT9X7hYOdOb?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1) to show my idea. Main issue was connected to `mouse up` emitted before `click` event. I've my small changes in `mouseup` listener in mentioned directive.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer. Please show working code

Comment: @PatricioVargas there is no any "code" word in SO [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Yeah there's not, but follow @Eliseo example, for this case this person needs workable code as an answer not just words. Sounds like you know how to do it, why don't you show him with code then?

Comment: While reading the question, I've just assumed that @tom needs an idea. But I'll try to edit my answer and provide working code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20909295)

Comment: @Lal could you be more precise in which point my answer does not provide an answer? One more time, does answer need to provide code for copy&paste? If so, please provide a link to such rule. I have shared an idea - a point from which the author can start. After suggestion, I have added an example how to implement it. I have also provide the explanation what was the cause that first implementation was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works and is quite compact but maybe not so elegant. Someone might post a better one. What I did was extend the directive a bit so it exposes a boolean variable to the view that tells whether the event fired:

```
import {
  Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[custMousehold]', exportAs: 'custMousehold' })
export class MouseholdDirective {

  @Input() duration: number = 350; // ms
  @Output() mousehold: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() fired: boolean;
  public timeout: any;

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  mousedown(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.fired = false;
    if (event.which !== 1) return; // left mouse button only
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.fired = true;
      this.mousehold.emit(event);
    }, this.duration);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseup')
  mouseup() { clearTimeout(this.timeout); }

}
```

In the view I can access this `fired` variable like this:

```
<span custMousehold #custMousehold="custMousehold" (click)="!custMousehold.fired ? ...
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38582320/5214911)