# how to use variable in ngContainer

Tags: angular

```
 <ng-container "let test= someList[1]"></ng-container>
```

I want use variable in ng-container

But that code is not working. How to make it right?

Comment: You can check the answer right here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<ng-container "let test = someList[1]">
  {{test.name}} //if someList[1] is an object 
  {{test}} //if someList[1] is something like [1,2,3....]
</ng-container>
```