# Angular 6 alias on HTML

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to use some element in HTML with angular 6 more then once and I want to save that element as alias, but I can't do that if the directive or element isn't `*ngIf`.

let say I have this code -

```
<dumb-comp
    [name]="(someObservable | async).name"
    [role]="(someObservable | async).role"
    [age]="(someObservable | async).age">
</dumb-comp>
```

I have to use async pipe each time... I want to keep `(someObservable | async)` on an alias and use it every time that I need ... is there any solution for that?

I want to use that without `*ngIf`, and I want to know please why is that possibly only using `*ngIf`.

**I know that I can pass all the data to the dumb-comp but I want to filter the data before. the code here is just an example for a bigger problem**

Comment: The data are not exist on the observable variable,  the observable just get notified when new data is coming. you can use middle-ware to save a copy of your last data in your service or your component

Answer (score 2):

assign the result to variable

```
<dumb-comp *ngIf="someObservable | async as res"
     [name]="res.name"
     [role]="res.role"
     [age]="res.age">
 </dumb-comp>
```

Comment: i know i can use ngIf but i dont wnat to use that in my case, and actually i realy want to understand what i can use it only on ngif

Comment: why are u not using ngIf

Comment: This isn't a dummy way to do this. ngIf wait until observable resolve and then assign it to a variable. Otherwise, you will get an error accessing `res` variable. ngIf prevent us from that

Answer (score 1):

It's a missing and highly requested [feature](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15280) of angular. Unfortunately they are not very eager to add it. You can however create your own custom directive and use it. However this will perform poorly compared to a native angular template syntax.

For an `*ngLet` example, you can check [this](https://github.com/ngrx-utils/ngrx-utils/blob/master/projects/store/src/directives/ngLet.ts) implementation of ngrx.

If you've added this, you can change your template to this:

```
<dumb-comp *ngLet="someObservable | async as res"
  [name]="res?.name"
  [role]="res?.role"
  [age]="res?.age">
</dumb-comp>
```

As mentioned, this will cause the `res` to be `undefined/null` while waiting for the observable to resolve.

If multiple subscriptions are your worry, you can use the `share()` operator. This will share the subscription amongst the subscribers, then you can use the `async` pipe as much as you want (on that observable) without any serious performance impact

Comment: So bottom line, you can not do this in built-in way on angualr ?

Comment: @NaorTalmor read the github issue I've attached. There is no way, although most of the cases `*ngIf` does what you want. It get's messy though when the observable returns a falsy value, and you still want to render the child component. In this case you can use the `*ngIf="{res: someObservable | async} as data"` notation, or go for the custom `ngLet` directive