# Angular 8 accordion with Dynamic data without using bootstrap/angular material

Tags: html, css, angular8

I am trying to implement accordion functionality without using bootstrap/angular material accordion. My data is coming dynamically from an api.

I tried doing below but that opens and closes all the panels together. I understand the reason behind it but I don't understand how to approach.

Component.ts

```
export class AccordionComponent implements OnInit {
    isHidden = true;
    mFaqs: IFaq[];
    constructor(private faqService: FaqService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.faqService.getFaqs()
            .subscribe(faqData => this.mFaqs = faqData );
    }

}
```

component.html

```
<div class="custom-header" hideToggle="true" (click)="isHidden = !isHidden" *ngFor="let faq of mFaqs?.faqs">
    <section>
        <section>
            Q: {{ faq.question }}
        </section>
        <p [hidden]="isHidden">
            {{ faq.answer }}
        </p>
    </section>

</div>
```

It should only close/open the clicked one.

Comment: check `details summary` html tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass unique id for that.

Might be it'll help you.

[Angular on click event for multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889291/angular-on-click-event-for-multiple-items/56889689#56889689)

please go through it.

Comment: Sourav Raj: Huge thanks for your answer! It did work for me :)