# Testing Angular Directives

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I have an angular directive that attaches to an event on the element:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {
    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) click(event: Event): void {
        debugger;
        console.log(event); // <-- this is null in unit tests, MouseEvent when running the app normally
    }
}
```

This works fine, but for some reason the event parameter is `null` when unit testing the directive.

My Karma Jasmine unit test setup:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, DebugElement, ElementRef, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

@Component({
    selector: 'host-component',
    template: `
        <input type="text" myDirective id="findMe"/>
    `
})
class HostComponent {
}

describe(`MyDirective`, () => {
    let host: HostComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<HostComponent>;

    let debugElement: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                CommonModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                HostComponent, MyDirective
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HostComponent);
        host = fixture.componentInstance;

        debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#findMe'))

        fixture.autoDetectChanges();
    });

    describe(`should listen to the events`, () => {
        it(`should listen to the click event`, () => {
            fixture..triggerEventHandler('click', null);

            fixture.detectChanges();
            // expect...
        });
    });
});
```

Now, the problem: The directive is being hit in the unit test, but there is no `event` sent through as a parameter.

> I've followed this example: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/directives/ but unfortunately it doesnt use the event parameter.

**Edit**

I've also followed [this example](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/four-ways-of-listening-to-dom-events-in-angular-part-2-hostlistener-1b66d45b3e3d#3508) to pass through arguments to the `@HostListener()` decorator:

```
@HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event.target.id']) 
    onMouseEnter(id: string) {
        // Logs the id of the element 
        // where the event is originally invoked.  
    console.log(id);
}
```

**Edit 2**

It seems that the events raised from the DebugElement does not really represent the actual event listeners from the DOM element?

From what Hojou said [on this angular github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22148#issuecomment-376811217), if you trigger the event from the nativeElement it works. So the following code does send through the event to the directive, just not too sure if its the *right* way:

```
describe(`should listen to the events`, () => {
    it(`should listen to the click event`, () => {
        // fixture.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
        debugElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(newEvent('click'));

        fixture.detectChanges();
        // expect...
    });
});

function newEvent(eventName: string) {
    const customEvent: CustomEvent<any> = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');  // MUST be 'CustomEvent'
    customEvent.initCustomEvent(eventName, false, false, null);
    return customEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the **Edit 2**, raising a custom event does the trick and sends through the attached element of the directive

From what Hojou said on [this angular github issue (#22148, currently 'Open')](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22148#issuecomment-376811217), if you trigger the event from the nativeElement it works. So the following code does send through the event to the directive, just not too sure if its the right way:

```
describe(`should listen to the events`, () => {
    it(`should listen to the click event`, () => {
        // fixture.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
        debugElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(newEvent('click'));

        fixture.detectChanges();
        // expect...
    });
});

function newEvent(eventName: string) {
    const customEvent: CustomEvent<any> = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');  // MUST be 'CustomEvent'
    customEvent.initCustomEvent(eventName, false, false, null);
    return customEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null there because you are passing `null` as an argument in

```
fixture..triggerEventHandler('click', null);
```

which I assume is a typo and should be

```
debugElement.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
```

if you pass an object there you will see it being logged in the directive

```
debugElement.triggerEventHandler('click', {test: 'test'});
```

I would add that personally I would do this test by 'executing' a click on the actual DOM object, so you don't need to specify / stub the event yourself, this seems to make for a more trustworthy test.

So you instead of the `triggerEventHandler` line you would do something like

```
debugElement.nativeElement.click()
```

Comment: Did you try this? Its sending through null whatever you pass through there, or I might be missing something.. Either way, the directive should send through what is expected surely, as defined in the `@HostListener()`, which is the bound `'$event'`

Comment: I'm still sending through `null` using `element.dispatchEvent` but that one is working...

Answer (score 0):

You do not test directives directly. You test them via a test component. Here I am testing the *ngVar directive described here - [How to declare a variable in a template in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular)

The main take away here is when testing a directive just use the exact same approach as when testing a component. And test the directive is behaving based on the test component doing what it should be doing!

```js
import { NgVarDirective } from './ng-var.directive';
import { Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DirectivesModule } from '../directives.module';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    template: '<ng-container *appNgVar="42 as myVar"><div>{{ myVar }}</div></ng-container>'
})
class TestComponent { }

describe('NgVarDirective', () => {
    let component: TestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent],
            imports: [DirectivesModule]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should create an instance (HTMLElement)', () => {
        const el: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        const div: HTMLDivElement = el.querySelector('div');
        expect(div.textContent).toBe('42');
    });

    it('should create an instance (DebugElement)', () => {
        const el: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
        const de: DebugElement = el.query(By.css('div'));
        expect(de.nativeElement.textContent).toBe('42');
    });
});
```

Another example here (which is not testing a structural directive, unlike my example above) https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/directives