# Angular define variable to be re-used in nested HTML elements

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to working with angular and I was reading through the documentation but I could not find the proper way to declare some kind of variable that can be reused in nested html elements.

As a work around I did something that works but I consider a bit dirty. I would like to know how a proper solution for this would look like.

Basically, what I have is the identifier 'someProperty' that I want to use in many places in the nested HTML elements. I may want to use it as the formControlName but also as an argument to function calls. Right now I abuse the *ngFor for this purpose to define variable 'x'.

```
<div class="container-row" *ngFor="let x of ['someProperty']">
  <span *ngIf="isReadOnly(x)" class="readonly-indicator"></span>
  <span *ngIf="!isReadOnly(x)" class="writable-indicator"></span>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="{{x}}"
           [readonly]="isReadOnly(x)"
           (change)="onChange($event, x)"
           placeholder="This is some Property!">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!someFormGroup.controls[x].valid">ERROR!</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: An alternative would be to abuse `*ngIf`. You can find other methods in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38582293/1009922).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `readonly` variable in your component as use that property as a constant.

```
readonly MY_PROPERTY = 'someProperty'
```

And use it in your template like this

```
<div class="container-row" *ngFor="let x of [MY_PROPERTY]">
```

I hope this helps.

UPDATE:

```
<div class="container-row" *ngFor="let x of ([MY_PROPERTY] as templateVariable)">
{{ formGroup.controls[templateVariable].value  }} 
</div>
```

Comment: Not really what I want. I want to specify the value of the variable in the HTML, not the component.ts file. I just don't want to have to copy the same string over and over.

Comment: use either static variables, or @inputs to children or an event system which ask parent to emit variable value, this requires child to subscribe to the parent event.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) that has form controls and you can get its value as array 
here see this post it will help you

[here is one](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/)  [another one](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a)

If that's what you need, please approve this as an answer