# How to get nested values of an observable using async pipe from html

Tags: html, angular, typescript, observable

I have some block of html in Angular that I would like fill out with some nested values of an observable, such as:

```
  <div class="container" *ngIf="(myObservable$ | async)  as myObservable">
    <span>{{ myObservable.middleNest.value1 }}</span>
    <span>{{ myObservable.middleNest.value2 }}</span>
  </div>
```

Is there a way to define a variable in the container tags so that I am able to fetch the nested values via middleNest.value1 and middleNest.value2 (ensuring the path to middle nest is fully non-null)? It doesn't seem right to have to write the whole path to middle nest in the spans, given that in some cases the values could be deeply nested.

Comment: You can try to implement this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43172992/4955934).

Answer (score 2):

You could use RxJS `pluck` operator in the controller to return only a specific property from the observable response

Controller

```js
export SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  myObservable$: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myObservable$ = this.someService.getData().pipe(
      pluck('middleNest')
    );
  }
}
```

Now you have the `middleNest` object in the `async` emission.

```html
<div class="container" *ngIf="(myObservable$ | async) as middleNest">
  <span>{{ middleNest?.value1 }}</span>
  <span>{{ middleNest?.value2 }}</span>
</div>
```

Also like @uiTeam324 showed, you could use safe navigation operator `?.` to avoid potential undefined errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `safeOperator(?)`. It will check for `undefined` internally

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="(myObservable$ | async)  as myObservable">
  <span>{{ myObservable?.middleNest?.value1 }}</span>
  <span>{{ myObservable?.middleNest?.value2 }}</span>
</div>
```